# concurrent states

Tags: traminer

I plan to use TraMineR for a research study on student course-taking patterns in secondary schools. For instance – Algebra, Geometry, Algebra II, etc. – where each course is a state. I wondered how to handle instances where students take two courses at once (say Algebra and Geometry in the same year)? Since I am considering each course a state – this would mean that there would be concurrent states in one year.

Can this be handled in TraMineR?

Answer (score 0):

`TraMineR` has no specific feature to dealing with such combinations of states.

A solution is to extend the alphabet with combinations of states by adding, for example, `Geometry.Algebra` to the list of possible states. Of course, if you intend to compute dissimilarity between sequences you will have to suitably set the substitution costs. E.g., the cost for substituting `Algebra` to `Geometry.Algebra` could be set at half the cost for substituting `Algebra` to `Geometry`. You could try to systematize this with the method `"FEATURES"` of the `seqcost` function of `TraMineR (>= v 2.0-5)`.